# how to get the googlemap api key for cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, google-maps

I am a beginner of cordova.
I have a problem to show the google map.
I can show the google map in website using javascript.
Also i can show the google map using java and xcode.

But not sure how can show the using cordova.  Because it is the javascript + html.

So I can make the code like following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works well on web browser of course.  My question is that what kind of key I should use?

At a first time I use the javascript key.  But it did not work on ios and android. I guess to run on android I should use andorid key.  But if yes how I can get the sha footprint key.  Same thing on ios. Without this I cannot get the android google map api key.   I am trying to find the solution but lots of video and document, if I use the javascript api key, it works well. But that is not true.  I am sure.  If yes how we can get the key? second is it right insert the android and ios key to the javascript code?

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that what kind of key I should use?

You should use the correct API key for whichever device the app is on.

If you head over to [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard), create an account if you dont already have one go > credentials > create credentials and select API key.
Create whichever ones you need, Android, iOS etc.

> Loading the script

You really should be checking the users internet connection to load an external script in an app [heres a tutorial for that](https://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2014/08/13/loading-google-maps-in-cordova-the-right-way/).

Basically using [cordova-plugin-network-information](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/) check the users connection status and if they are connected load the maps script.

```
(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    function onDeviceReady () {
        document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
        document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
        loadMapsApi();
    }

    function onOnline () {
        loadMapsApi();
    }

    function onResume () {
        loadMapsApi();
    }

    function loadMapsApi () {

        var API_KEY;

        if ( device.platform === 'Android') {
          API_KEY = 'youAndroidAPIkey';
        } else if ( device.platform === 'iOS') {
          API_KEY = 'youriOSAPIkey';
        }

        if(navigator.connection.type === Connection.NONE || google.maps) {
            return;
        }
        $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+API_KEY+'&sensor=true&callback=onMapsApiLoaded');
    }

    global.onMapsApiLoaded = function () {
        // Maps API loaded and ready to be used.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {});
    };

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
})(window);
```

*edit -------------*

I originally used [cordova-google-maps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) and IMHO it was too bloated and buggy for me to use in a commercial app.

Comment: thanks for your response.  Already I used this plug in,but it does not works for me.  can you explain why I cannot see the result?